Can't connect to WiFi6E on Raspberry Pi Zero2 W
I am trying to connect to a WiFi6E AP with a Raspberry Pi Zero2 W. Here are the details of the device I am using.

OS : Ubuntu Server 22.04.5
Wifi Antenna : TP-Link TXE70UH
driver : rtw8852cu from https://github.com/baldvin-kovacs/rtw8852cu

When I made it as it is, it did not have 2.4GHz bandwidth, so I took a measure to set the country setting in the Makefile to US. Also, NetworkManager is used to connect, and the SSID is displayed when the nmcli dev wifi list command is run.
However, when I try to connect, I get the following error.
Error: Connection activation failed: (53) The Wi-Fi network could not be found.

Can someone please help me?
